# Teams doesn't respect the setting "no notifications for reactions"

Tags: notifications, microsoft-teams

- **Teams version**: 1.5.00.5967
- **OS**: Windows 11

Teams has customisable settings for Notifications.

I want notifications for messages, replies, mentions etc. but not *likes and reactions*. Those are when someone replies to you, but not with text, with just a smiley-face or thumbs-up icon etc.

My settings are below.

Why do I still get a notification for those things?

[image: Teams settings dialogue box]

Comment: There are solutions for (1) feeds and for (2) meetings where you're admin. Will these solve your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've turned it off for teams and channels, but not for chats.

So, in teams, go to notification settings, and next to "Chat" click on "edit", then turn off the settings for "likes and reactions".

There's a tutorial on [techcult](https://techcult.com/how-to-stop-microsoft-teams-pop-up-notifications/), see steps 7 - 9